# Why do our iDevices give a page not found error when trying to connect to profile manager website?

Tags: iphone, ipad, server.app, profile-manager

I want to know if anyone have also encountered this. We can connect to Profile Manager using one of our iPads (server.website.com/mydevices), but we can't connect using the rest of the iDevices we have. There are no difference between that iPad and the rest of the iDevices that we have, so we're wondering on what went wrong. The error is that the browser can't find the page.

This is a big problem for us because we can't enroll the devices in Profile Manager.

Any information will help. If you need additional info, please put it in the comment section. Thank you.

EDIT: as mentioned by bmike, we already have the DNS and SSL working. It's just this very weird behavior of being able to access the profile manager on every mac and that single iPad but not on other devices. Also note that we don't have that much experience on server administration, and it's safe to say that we don't know what we're doing and just following settings by the books.

Comment: .local is a bag of hurt. Did you self sign a .local certificate? I would change the host name to a FQDN and redo SSL certs - self signed us fine for testing. Until you get DNS and SSL working, lion server will abuse you repeatedly.

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit the question. Actually the DNS and SSL is working.

Comment: @bmike we got it. It's a DNS issue. My colleague forgot that he manually set the DNS server in the one iPad where it worked. Now the routing has been fixed, and is working via 3G network.

Comment: Huzzah! Embedded systems can be so hard to troubleshoot without terminal access to dump the things we come to expect from a unix shell. Would you consider answering your own question properly in the answer section? You'll help others to see this has a resolution and isn't just a [tumbleweed](http://apple.stackexchange.com/badges/21/tumbleweed).

Comment: No problem. I'll ask my colleague what he did, and then put the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified that all required ports are open from the iPads to the server? (Port 1640 specifically, but also you'll want to ensure access to 80/443 for web and 2195/2196/5223 for push)

- [Lion Server: Ports used by Profile Manager](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5302)

You can also run some tests to see if this is a problem with the server itself or with the network. Connecting to the server's IP address from the iOS device will rule out DNS and other issues.

I've found it helpful to open the Console app and watch /var/log/apache2/access_log for incoming requests so you can see which iOS devices are getting through to the server. That log shows you the IPv4 or IPv6 address of each connection request so you can detect which devices are networked correctly to send traffic to the server and narrow down in the chain where your problem lies.

Hopefully this helps others with DNS issues in getting to the same resolution as you.